# Installing django-rest-auth, ' NameError: name 'FacebookLogin' is not defined '

Tags: django, django-rest-auth

I followed http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#registration-optional

As django-rest-auth installation doc said, i installed django-allauth first, but `url(r'^rest-auth/facebook/$', FacebookLogin.as_view(), name='fb_login'),
NameError: name 'FacebookLogin' is not defined` comes, and i don't know how to solve this.

**blog/views.py**
    url(r'^rest-auth/facebook/$', FacebookLogin.as_view(), name='fb_login'),
NameError: name 'FacebookLogin' is not defined

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import filters
from rest_framework import generics
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.views import FacebookOAuth2Adapter
from rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView


class FacebookLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = FacebookOAuth2Adapter
```

**blog/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from blog import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/$', views.post_list, name='list'),
    url(r'^blog/create/$', views.post_create, name='create'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.post_detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^rest-auth/facebook/$', FacebookLogin.as_view(), name='fb_login'),
    ]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'blog',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    ]

SITE_ID = 1
```

When i command python3 manage.py runserver,

it gives me

```
python3 manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f65f81601e0>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
        self.check(display_num_errors=True)
      File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
        include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
      File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
        new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
      File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
        return check_resolver(resolver)
      File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
        for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
      File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
        patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
      File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
        return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/mysite/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
        url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
      File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
        urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/home/keepair/djangogirls/blog/urls.py", line 14, in <module>
        url(r'^rest-auth/facebook/$', FacebookLogin.as_view(), name='fb_login'),
    NameError: name 'FacebookLogin' is not defined
```

Why this error has been occurred?

What is my fault?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Replace `FacebookLogin.as_view()` with `views.FacebookLogin.as_view()`. 
Error - `FacebookLogin` is not defined as urls.py doesn't have it.
Fault - You are using `FacebookLogin` but haven't imported it in the `urls.py`. But you have imported `views` so you can use `views.FacebookLogin`, OR you can `from blog.views import FacebookLogin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is self explanatory that `FacebookLogin` is not defined in `urls.py`.

Fault - You are using `FacebookLogin` but haven't imported it in the `urls.py`.

Solution:

You have imported blog.views in the urls.py, so replace `FacebookLogin.as_view()` with `views.FacebookLogin.as_view()`

```
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from blog import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/$', views.post_list, name='list'),
    url(r'^blog/create/$', views.post_create, name='create'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.post_detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^rest-auth/facebook/$', views.FacebookLogin.as_view(), name='fb_login'),
    ]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

OR

import the class itself `from blog.views import FacebookLogin`.